# How to pass a Value from OnRedirectToIdentityProvider to OnAuthenticationFailed in Owin startup

Tags: .net, openid-connect, owin, startup

I have owin and OIDC none MVC .net application.
I wonder if there is any way set a value (Like environment variable or parameter)  in OnRedirectToIdentityProvider in Owin Startup and access it in OnAuthenticationFailed?

I tried setParameter and Add.Environment but no luck. The context in OnAuthenticationFailed doe snot carry any of them.

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Maryam

Answer (score 0):

creating a concurrent dictionary will work but i used totally different approach.
SetParameter and Add.Environment will not work